# Stub "new Date()" with Cypress

Tags: cypress, stub

In my tests, "new Date()" returns the current date, but I want it return a constant object. But I don't know how to stub this. Example of what I would like :

```
cy.stub(Date, 'constructor', () => {
  return new Date(2020, 6, 24, 22, 19, 00)
})
```

How to do this ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach:

```
cy.clock(new Date(2020, 6, 24, 22, 19, 00), ['Date'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer: [Specify a now timestamp](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clock.html#Now).

In `app` code:

```
// element
<div id="mockedDate"></div>

// script
document.getElementById('mockedDate').innerText = new Date();
```

```
it('stub date', () => {
    cy.clock(new Date(2020, 6, 24, 22, 19, 0).getTime());
    cy.visit('http://localhost:8081/?j=test');
    cy.get('#mockedDate').invoke('text').then(cy.log);
});
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I tried this, but with this, some DOM elements are not clickables. I don't know why.

Comment: Not sure why you think it may be related?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about [cy.stubbing](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/stub) the `Date`, but for anyone experiencing [issues](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5305) when using `cy.clock` & having all sorts of `setIntervals` which break the `cy.visit`, etc.

I was able to mock the `new Date()` by simply overwriting the global `win.Date`

*my.spec.ts*

```js
export class FakeDate extends Date {
  constructor(date) {
    super(date)
    if (date) {
      return new Date(date)
    }
    // The date you want
    return new Date('Fri Apr 29 2022 01:59:59 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)')
  }
}
// ...
cy.visit('my-page', {
  onBeforeLoad(win) {
    win.Date = FakeDate
  }
})
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out why this is happening, however this implementation doesn't always mock Date() for me, and most importantly randomly gets the previous day?!
Even though I call the Date constructor always without any parameters, it ends up entering to if case or selects the static date randomly.